# ModuleNotFoundError with django

Tags: python, django

I want to use some fuctions from the other python files in my view context. In myapp I have created folder named "code" and inside this i have a file named "examplee.py". I try to import it like this views.py:
views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
# Create your views here.
import sys
sys.path.append('./code')
import examplee as expl
class CmtGraphTool(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        list = expl.test1()
        context = {list}
        return render(request, "cmtgraphtool.html", context)
```

and the examplee.py contains a simple function that returns a list of elements. The problem is that when i try to import and use the fuction test1 in my view then Spyder(my development enviroment) can see that function, but when i try to run django server by python manage.py runserver, it raises an error:

#### ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'examplee'

How to include fuctions from the other files in a way that django can see them?
Thanks;)

Comment: You certainly shouldn't be messing about with `sys.path` inside your views file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if its inside a folder and is inside the app directory and make sure to have a blank `__init__.py` file inside the code folder

then try this

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
# Create your views here.
from .code import examplee as expl
class CmtGraphTool(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        list = expl.test1()
        context = {list}
        return render(request, "cmtgraphtool.html", context)
```

Comment: I think we are getting closer to the solution, but after i did it i've got another error: No module named code.example; 'code' is not a package. Do You know what it might be?

Comment: try the edited ans, and make sure not to use sys in this type of cases